# How to Stop SAP B1 Form_Data_Add event if some criteria is not matching in Code ,not by the Validation Sql Query

Tags: c#, sapb1

When I am adding a Sales Order, I have a method For VAT checking.

The method returns data in bool.

If the bool value is `False` the Form_DATA_Add the event should not work further it should stop the adding process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `BubbleEvent` bool to handle whether you want the event to actually complete.

```
private static void OApplication_FormDataEvent(ref SAPbouiCOM.BusinessObjectInfo BusinessObjectInfo, out bool BubbleEvent)
    {
        //Foo as your bool method
        if (Foo())
        {
            BubbleEvent = true;
        }
        else
        {
            BubbleEvent = false;
        }
    }
```

Something like this should do the trick but I would strongly suggest to use the `SBO_SP_TransactionNotification` for things like that. Also manage the `BusinessObjectInfo.BeforeAction` bool to determine the exact moment you want the ckecks to trigger, I would suggest to go with `BusinessObjectInfo.BeforeAction = true`.

Comment: Its not happening with this code. Form_DATA_Add event in passed even by a error on the code

Comment: you catch it on `BusinessObjectInfo.BeforeAction = true` and it goes through with  `BubbleEvent = false;` and still the form is added?

Comment: Tbh I strongly suggest to use the SBO_SP_TransactionNotification. What your are trying to do seems like the exact thing it is supposed to do and messing with the UI of the form on `FormDataEvent` is risky and, I've found, not that reliable